# Counting the number of columns in logical matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, boolean-logic

I have a matrix like this in R:

```
matrix =
      1     2     3     4    5     6     7    8     9   10
X3  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE
X2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE
X1 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE TRUE  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

and I need to know how many columns have their 3 values in TRUE. The solution I'm looking for needs to be generic enough so it can be applied to any possible dimensions of the matrix. I tried

```
length(which(apply(matrix, 2, function(x) x[1] & x[2] & x[3])))
```

and that worked but it is not generic.

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Mariano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `colSums` on the logical matrix and check whether it is 3 i.e the number of rows of the matrix.  Get the `sum` of it.

```
sum(colSums(m1)==nrow(m1))
#[1] 3
```

As the OP used `apply`, it can be also done with `all`

```
sum(apply(m1, 2, all))
#[1] 3
```

As @RHertel mentioned in the comments, if the values are numeric and if 0 corresponds to FALSE and all other elements as TRUE, then change it to a logical matrix with `m1!=0` or `!!m1`, then do the `colSums` and the rest as above.

```
sum(colSums(!!m1) == nrow(m1))
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE), .Dim = c(3L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(c("X3", "X2", 
"X1"), c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10")))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @akrun! This is exactly what I was looking for.